# @OneToOne mapping does not work with @Inheritance

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, persistence

I have problem with mapping @OneToOne and deployment under jboss.

I have hierarchy of classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SEED")
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "ENTITY_TYPE")
@ForceDiscriminator
public class Parent implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEED_SEQ", sequenceName = "SEED_SEQ")
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEED_SEQ")
   @Column(name = "AA_ID")
   protected Long aaId;

   @Column(name = "SECRET_SEED")
   protected String seed;

   @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID") 
   protected String entityId; 

   //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "c1")
public class Child1 extends Parent
{
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "c2")
public class Child2 extends Parent
{
}
```

I have tried to map child class this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLINIC")
public class Clinic implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_CLINIC_RECID")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_CLINIC_RECID", sequenceName = "SEQ_CLINIC_RECID")
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "CODE")
   private String code;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "CODE", referencedColumnName = "ENTITY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Child1 child1;

   //getters and setters
}
```

When I deploy this on jboss-4.2.3.GA I have following exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(ENTITY_ID) of setup.entities.Clinic.child1 referencing setup.entities.Child1 not mapped to a single property
at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:16
5)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.FkSecondPass.doSecondPass(FkSecondPass.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(AnnotationConfiguration.java:428)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.
java:286)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1115)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1233)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java
:154)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:869)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:407)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
```

I use hibernate 3.2.6.ga, hibernate-entitymanager 3.3.1.ga.

Why do I get this error? Is my mapping is correct?

Comment: I don't see the "ENTITY_ID" field mapped in Child1 or Parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your referencedColumnName is referring to a "ENTITY_ID" when your id column in the Parent entity is "AA_ID". I think changing it to "AA_ID" would fix your problem. From the exception Hibernate is giving, it appears to be defaulting in a join column referring AA_ID and then also using the one you've defined. Then the exception says it is **not** mapped to a single property.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CODE", referencedColumnName = "AA_ID", insertable = false,     updatable = false)
private Child1 child1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately CODE field should be linked with ENTITY_ID and I can't change schema.

Comment: Where is "ENTITY_ID" mapped? is that missing in your example?

Comment: It mapped in Parent class:  @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID") protected String entityId;

Comment: I edited your example to include this. One thing you need to do is to make that unique: @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", unique = true)